# How to create deployment using python which uses `kubectll apply -f` internally

Tags: python, kubernetes, devops

**Can't replicate `kubectl apply -f` functionality with Python client**

I have created a deployment using `create_namespced_deployment` (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#create_namespaced_deployment) in python.

But when I tried to update the deployment manually using `kubectl apply -f`, I am getting warning message like below

```
Warning: resource deployments/fronend-deployment is missing the
kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is
required by kubectl apply. 

kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively
by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. 
The missing annotation will be patched automatically
```

I want to get rid of this warning message.Is there any other way?

I think the `create_namespced_deployment` method internally using `kubectl create -f` functionality.Is there any method that uses `kubectl apply -f`.

Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 4):

In order to supply a full answer, let's start by explaining the difference between
`kubectl apply` to `kubectl create`

---

#### `kubectl apply` vs `kubectl create`

The key difference between `kubectl apply` and `kubectl create` is that apply creates Kubernetes objects through a **declarative** syntax,
while the `create` command is **imperative**.

---

[image]

---

#### `apply`

- The `kubectl apply` is a cli command used to create or modify Kubernetes resources defined in a **manifest file**.
- Manifest file is referred to as **`Declarative`**.
- Using a **`Declarative`** files we "describe" what should be our **final** state of our cluster (regarding the resources which we define)
- The state of the resource is **declared in the manifest file** and this is where the name is coming from, then `kubectl apply` is used to implement that state.

#### `create`

- In contrast to `apply`, the create command `kubectl create` is used for **creating** a Kubernetes resource directly. (for example: `kubectl create ns XXX` which will create a namespace.
- This is an **Imperative** usage.
- You can also use `kubectl create` with a manifest file to create a **new instance** of the resource. However, if the resource already exists, you should get an error 9but most likely K8S will tolerate it and you will not see the error in most cases).

---

Hopefully, now you can understand the errors you keep getting.

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation between `kubectl create` and `kubectl apply`. Is there any method that does `kubectl apply` internally  or Any other method you can suggest to avoid the above warning? in Kubernetes /client-python. As I am currently using create_namespaced_deployment (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/AppsV1Api.md#create_namespaced_deployment) which does not work in this scenario.

Comment: Can I use any other method in python-Kubernetes(Note: I am having only spec file and namespace as inputs)? So that I can't see the above warning message on `kubectl apply` on the spec file.

Comment: Looks like @amanagantiramreddy is trying to modify the default behavior of kubernetes where in to disable the warning messages that comes when they use `apply` after using `create`. This is interesting and I am curious to know the solution.

Comment: If we need to modify the default behavior or suppress the warning messages, changes should apply to only `kubectl apply` command but not for other operations as it may have adverse affects @CodeWizard any thoughts?